# Is the integration of a gaussian function divided by polynomial possible?

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral, error-function

I am trying to evaluate the following integral:
\begin{equation}
I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left \{-\frac{(u-1)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\}\frac{1}{(u-x)^2+y^2}\mathrm{d}u
\end{equation}
where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Trying on mathematica tells me that the integral does not converge. Moreover I cannot use the residue theorem due to the $\exp\{-u^2\}$ term. 
However when plotting the function for certain $(x,y)$ values the function seems to have a closed area so I would expect the integral to converge given some restraints on $x$ and $y$. How does one tackle such integrals?

In a broader context, under what conditions does the following integral converge? 
\begin{equation}
I_\text{gen}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left \{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\}\frac{1}{ax^2+bx+c}\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\erfc}{erfc}$
The integral
$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-t^2}\mathrm{d}t}{\left\lvert t- z\right\rvert^2}&=\frac{\pi}{\Im z}\Re\left(\mathrm{e}^{-z^2}\erfc(-\mathrm{i}z)\right)
&&(\Im z \neq 0)\end{align}$$
is standard ([DLMF 7.19.4](https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.19#E4)).

Shift and rescale your integrals so that they look like the form on the left.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this identity! By rescaling, is the change of variables $u=\sqrt{2}\sigma t +1$ enough? It does take care of the exponential but then I get $|t\sqrt{2}\sigma+1-z|$ in the denominator. Sorry for asking something that is probably very simple, I just don't see it!

Comment: pull out the factor of $\sqrt{2}\sigma$, then shift and rescale $z$